# UISearchDisplayController and UITableView prototype cell crash

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UIViewController` setup in a storyboard with a `tableview` and `UISearchDisplayController`.

I am trying to use a custom prototype cell from self.tableview (which is connected to main tableview in the storyboard). It works fine if `self.tableview` had returned at least 1 cell when I load my view, but if `self.tableview` doesn't load a cell (as there is no data), and I load up the `UISearchBar` and search, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method crashes:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomSearchCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomSearchCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}

-(void)configureCell:(CustomSearchCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    User *user = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameLabel.text = user.username;
}
```

**Errors:**

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableViewRowData rectForRow:inSection:heightCanBeGuessed:]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'request for rect at invalid index path (<NSIndexPath: 0x9ef3d00> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0})
```

My fetchedResultsController seems to have data (1 section, 2 rows) at the point the above method is called. It crashes on the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` line.

Any pointers/ideas? It should dequeue the prototype cell from `self.tableview`, but my guess is there was none created in `self.tableview` so this is the cause?

Comment: Can you post the code of `configureCell:atIndexPath:` method? The problem may be in there

Comment: it crashes before it gets there... I will add it though

Comment: added above... doesnt really do much

Comment: After your `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` you must check `if (cell == nil)`, and if so, you need to create a cell.

Comment: Seems to work ok on the self.tableview though? Anyway, how do I instantiate from the prototype cell in the storyboard?

Comment: With the prototype cell defined in a storyboard, dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier should always return a valid cell.

Comment: This looks like it could be my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15895014/248168

Answer (score 60):

UISearchDisplayController manages it's own UITableView (filtered table), in addition to having your primary table.  The cell identifier in the filtered table doesn't match your primary table.  You also want to fetch the cell not by indexPath as both tables can be vastly different from each other with respect to number of rows, etc.

So instead of doing this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell =
[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier
forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

instead do this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell =
[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Comment: I was struggling for a good 2 hours on this. Your response helped a lot, particularly your note that your omit forIndexPath because the tables could have vastly different indices. Also, for other readers: make sure that you have self.tableview not just tableview.

Comment: SELF SELF SELF. using self like suggested here save my day. Thanks. It would be nice to know why,

Comment: The reason why is because self.tableView asks for a cell from your view controller's table view, which has the Prototype cell set. Just using tableView uses the ivar passed in the delegate method, which points to the search controller's table, which does not have a Prototype cell set. Doing self.tableView gets the cell from your main table view, but then uses it in the search table view.

Comment: But why does dropping the forIndexPath fix the crash? The mismatch indexPath makes sense, but then I thought I could do: [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView deque... forIndexPath:indexPath]; The tableView passed in to the delegate method is the searchResultsTableView. (Index path is 0 - 0). It still crashes, but works fine if I remove forIndexPath.

Comment: @owenfi From the docs, the `...forIndexPath:` version *uses the index path to perform additional configuration based on the cell’s position in the table view.* It seems that the "additional configuration" is a problem when the index path doesn't make sense in terms of the table's contents, and would obviously be unwanted if the requested cell is going to be used in a completely different table (which is what happens with UISearchDisplayController).

Comment: solved the problem exactly!  searched for 20 minutes to find this answer.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by duplicating the prototype cell into a new xib:

In viewDidLoad:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"CustomSearchCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"CustomSearchCell"];
```

And updated cellForRowAtIndexPath to use the method's tableview not the original self.tableview:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomSearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomSearchCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use à UISearchDisplayController in the methode celForRowAtIndexPath, you must use the tableView parameter methode and not the retain pointer of the controller.

try with this code

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomSearchCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomSearchCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: CustomSearchCell identifier doesn't exist on the UISearchDisplayController cell. It's a prototype cell on the original tableview in the storyboard. You cannot add a prototype cell to UISearchDisplayController in the storyboard... AFAIK